# How do I tell if a pandas column is a string or an ordered dict of the collection.OrderedDict variety

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-to-sql

Since I can't just do the to_sql directly if a column is an ordered dict, I want to be able to detect it and then turn it into a json.

Comment: you can get column type by `df.dtypes` attribute.

Comment: Coincidentally, its Object for both strings and ordered dict